# SSMS 18 Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows option is missing

Tags: ssms

The "Tabs and Windows" option is missing on SSMS 18.1. Can't pin/unpin query tabs. See attached screenshots.

My options

[image]

Expeceted options

[image]

Tried to uninstall/reinstall different versions (18/17.9.1/17.1/16.5.3) following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#uninstall-and-reinstall-ssms-17x) but had no luck.